# Windows Docker wmic

Tags: windows, docker, wmic, docker-for-windows

I am trying to determine what programs are installed in my Windows Docker Container (pulling from microsoft/windowsservercore). I thus followed this tutorial https://helpdeskgeek.com/how-to/generate-a-list-of-installed-programs-in-windows/.

However, when I run *wmic /output:C:\InstallList.txt product get name,version* I see *No Instance(s) Available*. How should I resolve this?

Comment: What exact syntax do you use to run that? Include your code with back ticks

Comment: I am not using any back ticks. I am running exactly this: wmic/output:C:\InstallList.txt product get name,version

Comment: When you run exact same command against server core installation (not inside docker), does it work?

Comment: Yes, I have to run CMD as admin but the InstallList.txt file is created listing out all the installed programs.

Comment: Use backticks to denote your code. Running following code `wmic /output:C:\InstallList.txt` does not produce any output for me regardless where I run it

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84926/pasting-code-into-stackoverflow-question-textbox

Comment: The output is the text file not stdout. I am running the command Administrator CMD Prompt in Windows 10.

Comment: Read my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting this response because you don't have anything installed on empty `servercore` image and hence `no instances` output. It would be the same output on empty OS installation. It's not docker specific. Below output of the same from server core image.

[image]